# sas insert table into html email

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, datastep

Is it possible to loop through the records of a table to populate an html email without repeating the beginning and the end of the email?

With this example I get a mail with 5 tables of 1 row (because `WORK.MyEmailTable` is table of 5 records and `set` creates a loop in the data step):

```
data _null_;
   file mymail;
   set WORK.MyEmailTable;

   put '<html><body><table>';

   ***loop through all records;
   put '<tr>';
   put %sysfunc(cats('<td>',var1,'</td>'));
   put %sysfunc(cats('<td>',var2,'</td>'));
   put %sysfunc(cats('<td>',var3,'</td>'));
   put '</tr>';

   put '</table></body></html>';

run;
```

And I'm looking to have 1 table of 5 rows.

I don't know if there is a way to prevent recursively `put` the beginning and the end of the mail when you use `set` in the data step.

(Let me know if it's not clear I'll update.)

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `_n_` automatic datastep variable to let you know when you are on the first observation, and the `set` statement option `end=` to know that you are on the last observation:

```
data _null_;
    file mymail;
    set WORK.MyEmailTable end=eof;

    if _n_ eq 1 then do;
      put '<html><body><table>';
    end;

    /*loop trhough all records*/
    put '<tr>';
    put %sysfunc(cats('<td>','_n_=',n,' eof=',eof,' ',var1,'</td>'));
    put %sysfunc(cats('<td>','_n_=',n,' eof=',eof,' ',var2,'</td>'));
    put %sysfunc(cats('<td>','_n_=',n,' eof=',eof,' ',var3,'</td>'));
    put '</tr>';

    if eof then do;
      put '</table></body></html>';
    end;
run;
```

I've added the values `_n_` and `eof` to the output so you can see clearly how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Rob's method is pretty much the standard, but there is another option if you prefer scripting an explicit loop (which can be more comfortable for non-SAS programmers to read).  This will function *exactly* like Rob's answer, and may well compile to the same machine code even.

```
data _null_;
    file mymail;

    put '<html><body><table>';
    do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (eof);
    /*loop trhough all records*/
      set WORK.MyEmailTable end=eof;
      put '<tr>';
      put %sysfunc(cats('<td>',var1,'</td>'));
      put %sysfunc(cats('<td>',var2,'</td>'));
      put %sysfunc(cats('<td>',var3,'</td>'));
      put '</tr>';
    end;
    put '</table></body></html>';
    stop;
run;
```

`_n_` here doesn't have any special meaning (like it does in Rob's answer); it's used by convention since this way it does effectively have the same meaning as it does normally.

You need to use the `end=eof` to create a variable `eof` which is true on the last record of the dataset; otherwise the data step will terminate prematurely (before actually hitting your final statement).  You also need the `stop` to tell it to not go back to the start - otherwise it will, and will put a new starting section, then terminate instantly when it hits the `set`.  (Try it and see.)

`do _n_=1 by 1 until (eof);` is a SAS-specific way of using an incremental loop; it's similar to the c/c++ `for (_n_=1; !eof; _n_++)` for example - it allows you to have an auto-incremented do loop whilst having a separate, unrelated stopping criteria.